# Detecting cloaking at the client side

Tags: hash, web, secret-sharing, bot

According to [this paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/45365.pdf)(reference: section IX), it may be possible for clients to detect cloaking. It basically says, whenever you fetch a page from a url(assumed to clicked from the search results),you(your browser) generates a digest of the page. Then we can compare this digest with the one associated with URL in the search results and conclude that page is been cloaked or not depending on the deviation of the digest results.

The paper further goes on to add that in case of dynamic web pages such as news website, this deviation might be significant and plus if a cloaking service serves a page with some additional button that can lead to spam, the digest will still be more or less same as we just added one button.

Is there a mechanism which overcomes this drawback? I was thinking of a solution:attaching nonce to every page and comparing the nonce given to user and crawler, but then as it turned out it was adding significant computation overhead. Is there a way through which I can test crawler and client are indeed getting same content in case of dynamic pages?

Comment: Dynamic pages differ not only because of expected changes over time, but other factors might determine what content is displayed (IP of client, A/B testing, feeds from external sources, etc.). Unless the server cooperates in some scheme, I'm not sure what you are asking is possible.